# how to avoid pylint to run on non python files

Tags: python, pylint

I have a project with some python files and some other format files (.txt, .dat). When I run pylint on my entire project, it is running on python modules. But in addition, it is running on other files also in the parent folder

```
project    
  src     
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
    internal_data.txt
  external_data.txt
  .pylintrc
```

My pylint output is containing the "external_data" as module and giving error

```
cd project
pylint ./* -rcfile ./.pylintrc --errors-only
************* Module external_data
external_data.txt:1:0: E0602: Undefined variable 'test' (undefined-variable)
```

Pylint is running on non python files at current directory. But in sub directories, only python files are included in the output

Comment: Add `# pylint: skip-file` to the beginning of any file where you don't wan pylint to run.

Comment: I don't think changing the filenames is a proper solution

Comment: try `pylint ./` without asterisk. Or even `pylint .`

Comment: It didn't work. It is giving empty output

Comment: @newbie , in case it wasn't clear, I meant add that line to the first line of the text file, not the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I know this ticket is a bit old, but I came here hoping for an answer, didn't find one... and then found out for myself, so I thought I'd share the knowledge.

In general my usage of pylint is running it on the files I've modified as part of a git branch. So I get a list of files using this command;

```
[me@here pylint-example]$ git diff --name-only main HEAD
example1.py
example2.txt
```

However, same as in the question this may contain non python files. What I've been doing is using grep on the git command to only include files that end in .py

```
pylint `git diff --name-only main HEAD | grep .py`
```

This is a bit inconvenient, doesn't play nice with CICD and is not cross-platform, but it turns out there's a better way. If you dont have one already, you can create a config file with this command

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > my-config-file
```

Inside the generated config will be many options, including `ignore-patterns`.
This accepts a regex, which we can use to exclude all files that **don't** end in .py

```
ignore-patterns=.*(?<!py)$
```

Now you can run pylint on a list of files that may or may not contain non-python files and it'll only pick linting issues on the python files.

Before:

```
[me@here pylint-example]$ pylint --rcfile=my-config-file `git diff --name-only main HEAD`
************* Module example1
example1.py:4:0: C0305: Trailing newlines (trailing-newlines)
************* Module example2
example2.txt:3:14: E0001: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 3) (syntax-error)

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -20.00/10 (previous run: 5.00/10, -25.00)
```

After:

```
[me@here pylint-example]$ pylint --rcfile=my-config-file `git diff --name-only main HEAD`
************* Module example1
example1.py:4:0: C0305: Trailing newlines (trailing-newlines)

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 5.00/10 (previous run: -20.00/10, +25.00)
```